# How to compare properties of objects inside a vector?

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, comparison

I have a couple of display objects moving around the screen, the all belong to the same `Vector`. 
I would like to create a function that lets me pick an object with the lowest `x` value at the moment the function is called.

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you. Or let me know what else do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy and if you're into programming, you should be able to do it yourself, but if you're a beginner, I'll give you some code:

```
var vec:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();

function getLowestXObject():DisplayObject 
{
    var minX:DisplayObject = vec[0];

    for(var i:int = 1; i < vec.length; i++) 
    {
        if(minX.x > vec[i].x)
        {
            minX = vec[i];
        }
    }
    return minX;
}
```